# package org.opencv.android does not exist After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, java-native-interface, android-studio-3.0

I have an Android project that uses OpenCV. It used to work before I upgraded Android studio to 3.0 (and gradle to 4.1).

The native library (`.so`) files remained in the same folder `/main/jniLibs`, but I get this error when trying to build:

```
error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
```

It looks like the `jni` files don't compile now. What is changed in the upgrade that cause this or how can I fix it?

Comment: can you add your gradle file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing it by deleting all the opencv files, the opencv library and the project (.iml) files. 
Then I created the project files again as new project and set up the opencv integration like shown in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heCVNFrdJ6M

I am not sure, but I guess the upgrade messed up (or did not properly fix) my project (.iml) files.